# Checking a substring from a programmatically added element in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form that adds a new line on a button click. The new line must check for logic independently. In this case, it's chacking the first 2 digits of a barcode and associating it to a data set to see if it matches and return the appropriate value or "nothing found". I can't seem to get this right. First, it's not really evaluating at all. It only gives me "No Agency found" and second, it's doing it for all fields (because they all have the same v-model on a new line add). How can I achieve this so that it evaluates correctly and independently from each other?

Here's the relevant code in my template and script

```
<div id="q-app" class="q-pa-lg">
 <div class="col-6">
  <div v-for="(barcodefield, index) in barcodefields" :key="index">
   <div class="flex q-pt-lg">
    <div class="row flex-center">
     <div class="col-3">
      <div class="column">
       <div class="row q-pr-lg items-center">
        <label class="text-weight-medium">Starting Roll #:</label>
        <q-input outlined square dense maxlength="24"
         v-model.trim="barcodefield.start" ref="bcentry"></q-input>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-3">
      <div class="column">
       <div class="row q-pr-lg items-center">
        <label class="text-weight-medium">Ending Roll #:</label>
        <q-input outlined square dense maxlength="24"
         v-model.trim="barcodefield.end" @blur="showAgencyName" ref="bcentry"></q-input>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-5">
      <div class="column">
       <label class="text-weight-medium">
        Agency:
       </label>
       <div v-if="agencyName" style="min-height: 40px">
        {{ agencyName }}
       </div>
       <div v-else style="min-height: 40px"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-1">
      <div class="block float-right">
       <q-btn v-if="index + 1 === barcodefields.length" @click="addLine" icon="add" color="primary" round />
       <q-btn v-else style="min-width: 42px"/>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
        barcodefields: [],
        barcodeprefixes: {
            "10": "Boston",
            "11": "New York",
            "13": "Houston",
            "14": "Connecticut",
            "16": "SIA",
            "17": "Colorado",
            "18": "Chicago",
            "19": "Washington",
        },
        barcodefield: {
          star: "",
          end: ""
        },
        agencyName: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addLine() {
        this.barcodefields.push({
            start: null,
            end: null
        });
    },
    showAgencyName() {
        var str = this.barcodefield.end;
        var res = str.substring(0, 2);
        if (this.barcodeprefixes[res] == undefined) {
            this.agencyName = "Agency not found";
        } else {
            this.agencyName = this.barcodeprefixes[res];
        }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.addLine();
  } 
}
```

Here is a [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/oNXvrbK?editors=1010) for you.

Comment: One thing that's definitely a problem: you loop through all the barcode fields and set up a v-model on *each* input, but each row's inputs point to the same attributes.

Comment: Also, should agency name be different (possibly) for each row? That's not currently possible.

Comment: @ebbishop correct. The agency name can be different or the same. Depending n the prefix typed in the second textbox

Comment: Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/7r1pqx9f/. I'm writing up an explanation of my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on here:

First, as Simon points out, don't name loop variables the same thing as a top-level data element. Instead of `<div v-for="(barcodefield, index) in barcodefields" :key="index">`, do `<div v-for="(item, index) in barcodefields" :key="index">`. Then update all the `barcodefield.start` and `barcodfield.end` references to `item.start` and `item.end`.

Then, you need to get each item to have its own `agencyName`, instead of all of them referring to the same data.

Update `showAgencyName` to this:

```
showAgencyName(item) {
    var str = item.end;
    var res = str.substring(0, 2);
    if (this.barcodeprefixes[res] == undefined) {
        item.agencyName = "Agency not found";
    } else {
        item.agencyName = this.barcodeprefixes[res];
    }
},
```

Then you can call it like this: `@blur="showAgencyName(item)"`

And use it in the html like so:

```
<div v-if="item.agencyName" style="min-height: 40px">
    {{ item.agencyName }}
</div>
```

(And you can get rid of the top-level `barcodefield` in the data object, because it's not used anymore.)

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/7r1pqx9f/

Comment: Outstanding! and very clear and concise explanation. Thank you so much....I know I didn't ask for this but id there a way to initialize the loop to start with 10 lines and then the button takes it from there? Sorry, new to mid level in Vue

Comment: Instead of running `addLine` on mount, you could set `barcodefields` to `[{start: '', end: '', agencyName: ''}...]` with as many items as you want, right in the data function. The button will still only show on the last line, and each time you click, it'll add a new one.

Comment: Wow! That easy! haha. Don't I feel like a jacka$$ now! hahahaha Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problem with this. 
First, you have a typo in the `barcodefield` data object. You have "star" instead of "start".

Secondly in the `showAgency` method you are referencing the `this.barcodefield` properties but that doesn't exist.
What you can do is pass the index of the barcodefield to the showAgencyName method, and use that inside the method to get the desired barcodefield from the `barcodefields` array.

In your html:

```html
<q-input outlined square dense maxlength="24"
v-model.trim="barcodefield.end" @blur="showAgencyName(index)" ref="bcentry"></q-input>
```

and the showAgencyName method:

```js
showAgencyName(index) {
    const barcodefield = this.barcodefields[index]
    var str = barcodefield.end;
    var res = str.substring(0, 2);

    if (this.barcodeprefixes[res] == undefined) {
        this.agencyName = "Agency not found";
    } else {
        this.agencyName = this.barcodeprefixes[res];
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
There is another problem that I didn't notice at first. The `agencyName` is overwritten every time you add a new barcodefield since it is kind of a global value. 
I update the Codepen with the simplest solution I could think of. Return the name of the agency from the `showAgencyName` and use that to print it on the interface. There are many possible other solutions to this (for example add the name the the barcodefields object in the array).

Here is a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gere/pen/eYNOqvY)

Comment: Close, but the agency is being affected in all lines when one changes, it adds the same value to all

Comment: Ah, of course, I updated the Codepen, and now will update the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

- First you should change name of the for loop variable named "barcodefield", beacause you already have one in your data structure
- Second, i would personnaly use a function `{{ getAgencyName(b) }}` instead of `{{ agencyName }}` otherwise you will have same agency name for all lines